# highlight a box in a list according to a condition in another table

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two tables :

Table 1 (overall Score )
[image: overall]

Table 2 (weekly score )
[image: weekly]

I have a leaderboard where I am echoing the overall score value **from Table 1** :

[image: lb]

**Problem :** What I am trying to do here is that whoever scores "-10" in table 2 (weekly score) , I want to alert the user by highlighting the color of their box in the leaderboard ,which is yellow now, to red.

current css involved :

```css
li mark div {
    display: block;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #eebb55;
    border-radius: 7pt;
    background: grey;
}
```

Php involved to display the list.This is for "overall" (right tab in leader board) .Similar exist for weekly too .

```html
<div id="overalllb" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
    <div class="leaderboard">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <mark>
                    <?php  while( $toprow2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) {
                        echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow2['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow2['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";
                    } ?>
                </mark>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

Queries passed to retrieve info from both the tables :

**1.query 1** - to find out all the employees with a score of -10.

```html
$q200 = " select *
  from Table2
  where  WeekNumber = 'week1' and pointsRewarded = '-10';";
  $stmt200=sqlsrv_query($conn,$q200);
  if($stmt200==false)
  {
  echo 'error to retrieve info !! <br/>';
  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
  }
```

**query 2- to retrieve from table 1 all the employees :**

```html
$q20 = "select *
  from EmployeeTable
  order by Total_points_Rewarded desc";
  $stmt20=sqlsrv_query($conn,$q20);
  if($stmt20==false)
  {
  echo 'error to retrieve info !! <br/>';
  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
  }
```

I am using PHP,Please suggest me a way to do it.God bless.

Comment: Could you please post the script that you are using to display this list?

Answer (score 1):

By joining the two tables in the SQL statement, you could simplify the process. Use the code from dhi_m above, but the data would come from a single SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    `table1`.`EmployeeName`,
    `table1`.`Overallpoints`,
    `table1`.`overallRank`,
    `table1`.`Total_points_Rewarded`,
IF(`Table2`.`points` = '-10','red-css-class','green-css-class') AS `display_status`
FROM `Table1`
LEFT JOIN `table2`
    ON `table1`.`EmployeeID` = `table2`.`EmployeeID`
WHERE `table1`.`WeekNumber` = 'week1'
ORDER BY `Table1`.`Total_points_Rewarded` DESC
```

The HTML code for the list would then look something like:

```
<div id="overalllb" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
    <div class="leaderboard">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <mark>
                    <?php  while( $toprow2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) {
                        echo  "<div class='".$toprow2['display_status']."'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow2['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow2['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";
                    } 
                    ?>
                </mark>

            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

*(Not tested, may contain typos)*

Comment: @Solan I understand that,but dont want to create an another table, unnecessarily.

Comment: I am thinking, we can compare the names in both the queries and similar names would have a red color box

Comment: @jane theSQL query above doesn't create a new table, and it compares the names (actually, the employee ID) in the join on clause. The if() statement determines the color of the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in a simple php if..else for highlighting it..

say you store specific score of user when inside users loop in $usersscore

```
if($usersscore<=-10){
    $highlightclass="redmark";
 }
else{
   $highlightclass-"yellowmark";
}
```

**In html**
    inside class of html element   you can echo it like

```
<li class="<?php echo $highlightclass; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
    <style>

    li mark div .parent-div-green {
        display: block;
        margin: 4px;
        padding: 5px;
        min-height: 50px;
        border: 2px solid #eebb55;
        border-radius: 7pt;
        background: grey;
    }

    li mark div .parent-div-red {
        display: block;
        margin: 4px;
        padding: 5px;
        min-height: 50px;
        border: 2px solid red;
        border-radius: 7pt;
        background: grey;
    }
</style>
<div id="overalllb" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
    <div class="leaderboard">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <mark>
                    <?php  while( $toprow2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) {

                        $divClass ="parent-div-green";
                        /****** Here write a query/function or join the two tables to fetch the Table2 $toprow2['EmployeeID']'s' `points` field value to the variable `$points` ********/
                        if($points == -10)  $divClass = "parent-div-red";
                        echo  "<div class='".$divClass."'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow2['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow2['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";
                    } 
                    ?>
                </mark>

            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.But its not working.I have written the two queries also to retrieve information from both the tables.We just need to math the names in both the places,if name matches we would make its box- border red.

Comment: No problem .The issue is that we need to match the names in both the tables and if it matches that names is red else green.I am saying so coz the query1 above will bring the names who has "-10" as points.

Comment: So,Unfortunately ur code isnot working.

Comment: if ($toprow20['EmployeeName'] == $toprow200['EmployeeName']) then red else green....!!

Comment: You want to get the EmployeeName/EmployeeID from table 2 with the `points` equal to -10, right?

Comment: yes.. and then only for those names,i will change the color to red in the names fetched from other query

Comment: If you have already this result array then it's better to compare with EmployeeIDs. In the case EmployeeName you need to take care of case sensitivity. Just try with  if ($toprow20['EmployeeID'] == $toprow200['EmployeeID'])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132400/discussion-between-jane-and-dhi-m).